Responsive email not responsive in Gmail
I have created a responsive html email file with mjml.
The email is dislayed properly when I test with Litmus but I lost the responsive aspect when I try to send it with my gmail account(it keeps the same render).
I think something is wrong with my method to import the html into gmail: I copy the rendered html opened in my browser in my email.
How to properly import my responsive html into gmail?
Thanks a lot

edit: It works when I forward the test email sent by Litmus. But I will gladly take a more direct way to do it.

If you are using Gmail to send the email out you can use an extension to import the email code in the composer.
Second, if the template loses its layout while sending through Gmail, probably because the HTML code you got from MJML has media queries that get blocked, you need to remove the media queries like mj-column-90, which are the width of columns, and replace it with the inline CSS in px and not in percentage like max-width:500px !important; width:100%!important;
This always fixes the problem for me.
